# Nested SQL SUM with WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to calculate cost of items sold in a day and total discount given in a day.

Table Structure is

```
sale Table
invoice_no | bill_date | discount | ...
```

The child table is (invoice_no is FK with sale table)

```
sale_items Table
invoice_no | item_no | cost_price | qty
```

This query works fine

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(p.cost_price*p.qty) FROM sale_items p
        WHERE p.invoice_no=s.invoice_no) as tcost_amount
 FROM sale s
 WHERE bill_date= '2017-05-26'
```

but when I want to **calculate discount** from parent table, `tcost_amount` sum up all rows in the child table without bill_date criteria, I am confused.

```
SELECT SUM(discount), (SELECT SUM(p.cost_price*p.qty)
                       FROM sale_items p
                       WHERE p.invoice_no=s.invoice_no) as tcost_amount
FROM sale s
WHERE bill_date= '2017-05-26'
```

My question is why `bill_date= '2017-05-26'` condition is not applying to `sale_items` in the second case?

Comment: Can sale table have duplicate invoice_no?

Comment: no, in sale table it is unique, but in sale_items it could repeat (as it is foreign key)

Comment: Then you dont need to sum discount because it has a single value to a invoice_no

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using mysql database

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you need to join the tables. something like this:

```
select (sum(si.cost_price * si.qty) - s.discount)
from sale s
inner join sale_items si on si.invoice_no = s.invoice_no
where s.bill_date = '2017-05-26'
```